# While loading site it show all menus for seconds

Tags: magento2, php

While loading my site it show all menus for some seconds and then it disapears and all is normal. How can I solve this issue? I searched for it and read something about preloader.

Comment: Please list all the errors/issues you are facing when loading website. Let us know which steps to take in order to replicate the issues please add screenshots to make sure we fully understand what you're referring to.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135333)